# C# Protobuf-net: Dictionary of decimals: Zeroes don't get roundtrip properly

Tags: c#, decimal, protobuf-net

I've found a weird bug around serialization/deserialization of decimal zeroes in protobuf-net, wondering if anyone has found a good workaround for this, or if this is actually a feature.

Given a dictionary like above, if i run in linqpad:

```
void Main()
{
    {
        Dictionary<string, decimal> dict = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
        dict.Add("one", 0.0000000m);
        DumpStreamed(dict);
    }

    {
        Dictionary<string, decimal> dict = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
        dict.Add("one", 0m);
        DumpStreamed(dict);
    }
}

public static void DumpStreamed<T>(T val)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Console.Write("Stream1: ");
        ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(stream, val);
        foreach (var by in stream.ToArray())
        {
            Console.Write(by);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Stream2: ");
        stream.Position = 0;
        var item = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<T>(stream);
        using(var stream2 = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(stream2, item);
            foreach (var by in stream2.ToArray())
            {
                Console.Write(by);
            }

        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("----");
}
```

I'll get two different streams:

First serialization: 1091031111101011822414

Second serialization: 107103111110101180

(The 0.0000000m gets converted to 0 on deserialization).

I've found this is due to this line of code in ReadDecimal:

```
 if (low == 0 && high == 0) return decimal.Zero;
```

Does anyone know why zeroes are getting normalized only during deserialization, and not on serialization?

Or any workaround for either consistently normalizing or consistently not normalizing decimal zero in a dictionary on serialization/deserialization?

Comment: Added the full code block, sorry about that.
The importance isn't preserving the zero, its more in the difference of byte streams  generated. The byte streams produced are different, which leads to false positives around the dictionaries being different.

Comment: (cross referencing the github issue for the "long tail": https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/issues/402)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep; the problem is this well-meaning but potentially harmful line:

```
    if (low == 0 && high == 0) return decimal.Zero;
```

which neglects to check `signScale`. It should really be:

```
    if (low == 0 && high == 0 && signScale == 0) return decimal.Zero;
```

I'll tweak that for the next build.

(edit: I ended up removing that check completely - the rest of the code is just some integer shifts etc, so having the "branch" is probably more expensive than *not* having it)

Answer (score 0):

Floating point data types are actually structures with several elements. Among them are base value and an exponent to which the base value is to be raised. The c# documentation for `decimal` states the following:

> The binary representation of a Decimal number consists of a 1-bit sign, a 96-bit integer number, and a scaling factor used to divide the integer number and specify what portion of it is a decimal fraction. The scaling factor is implicitly the number 10, raised to an exponent ranging from 0 to 28

So for example you could represent 1234000 as

- A base value of 1234000 x 10 ^ 0
- A base value of 123000 x 10 ^1
- A base value of 12300 x 10 ^ 2

etc.

So this problem isn't just limited to zero. All decimal values could be represented more than one way. If you are relying on the byte streams to check for equivalence, you're in for a lot of problems. You really shouldn't be doing that, as you will definitely get false positives, not just for zero either.

As for normalization while serializing, I think that is a problem specific to ProtoBuf. You could certainly write your own serialization that takes steps to normalize the data, although it might be tricky to figure out. Another option is to convert the decimals to some custom class before storage, or store them as their string representations, as odd as that may sound.

If you are interested in monkeying around with some decimals and inspecting the raw data, see the [GetBits()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Or you could use this extension method to view the in-memory representation and see for yourself:

```
public static unsafe string ToBinaryHex(this decimal This)
{
    byte* pb = (byte*)&This;
    var bytes = Enumerable.Range(0, 16).Select(i => (*(pb + i)).ToString("X2"));
    return string.Join("-", bytes);
}
```

Comment: while this is all *true*, it isn't really relevant to the question IMO; protobuf-net is already using `GetBits` etc, and is aware of scale.

Comment: Hi @MarcGravell. I think you are reading my answer as if it were addressed to you. It is addressed to the OP, who is conflating binary equality with numerical equality, with potentially disastrous results.

Comment: I really don't think they are (conflating binary equality with numerical equality); they just want it to round-trip predictably, which is very reasonable

Comment: See comment *The importance isn't preserving the zero, its more in the difference of byte streams generated. The byte streams produced are different, which leads to false positives around the dictionaries being different*. Please consider commenting on this aspect in your already excellent answer.

Comment: to be honest, I'm far more concerned with the fact that it was silently changing the data; it wasn't actually a false positive - it was a true positive: the data was different (invalidly); your answer here explains why they might have thought it was a false positive, when it was actually a true positive, but... I'd rather fix the code to make it a true negative :)