# Are there different decimal values for zero?

Tags: c#, decimal

I am working in C# code that assigns decimal values in the following ways. Are these the same values, or is there a difference?

```
decimal a = 0;
decimal b = 0m;
decimal c = 0.00m;
```

Comment: Yes there are differences. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807668/c-sharp-protobuf-net-dictionary-of-decimals-zeroes-dont-get-roundtrip-properl Does that matter? 99% of the time, no it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just adding a tiny bit more practical information to the other good answers

*Decimals* have many internal representations of `0`, however they will all equal *zero* when *compared*

[Decimal Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> The binary representation of a Decimal value consists of a 1-bit sign,
>   a 96-bit integer number, and a scaling factor used to divide the
>   96-bit integer and specify what portion of it is a decimal fraction.
>   The scaling factor is implicitly the number 10, raised to an exponent
>   ranging from 0 to 28. Therefore, the binary representation of a
>   Decimal value the form, ((-296 to 296) / 10(0 to 28)), where -(296-1)
>   is equal to MinValue, and 296-1 is equal to MaxValue.
>
> **The scaling factor also preserves any trailing zeros in a Decimal
>   number. Trailing zeros do not affect the value of a Decimal number in
>   arithmetic or comparison operations. However, trailing zeros might be
>   revealed by the ToString method if an appropriate format string is
>   applied.**

Example of changing the scaling factor

```
string GetBits(decimal d)
{
   var bits = decimal.GetBits(d);
   return $"{d==0} {d,31}  {bits[3],10:X8}{bits[2],10:X8}{bits[1],10:X8}{bits[0],10:X8}";
}

Console.WriteLine(GetBits(0));
Console.WriteLine(GetBits(0.0m));
Console.WriteLine(GetBits(0.000m));
// Manually set the Scaling Factor and Sign
Console.WriteLine(GetBits(new decimal(0,0,0,true,10)));
```

**Output**

```
Equals 0                    ToString       Other        Hi       Mid        Lo
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
True                               0    00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000
True                             0.0    00010000  00000000  00000000  00000000
True                           0.000    00030000  00000000  00000000  00000000
True                    0.0000000000    800A0000  00000000  00000000  00000000
```

Answer (score 4):

There is indeed a difference, but it is one that likely won't be a problem if you know about it.

Firstly as pointed out by Ben Cottrell in his answer all of those values will test equal.  In fact `decimal a = 0;` will cast the `0` value to `0m` which makes it actually identical to `b`.  Both `a` and `b` will test as equal to `0.00m` or any other variation of number of decimal places.

Where the difference comes in is when you're looking at the internals.  This is only really relevant when you're serializing the decimals as byte arrays or using the array returned by `decimal.GetBits()`.  In that case `0M` is 16 x 0 bytes while `0.00M` has a scale of 2, so one of the bytes in the binary representation (byte 14) is non-zero.

Also the string form of the two will differ, so comparing strings will fail:

```
decimal a = 0M;
decimal b = 0.00M;
if (a.ToString() != b.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine($"'{a}' != '{b}'");
```

So while they are equal they are still different.